# OpenSSL digest: different results on command-line and in c++

Tags: c++, hash, command-line, openssl

When I calculate the sha256-digest of a file with openssl-command-line it differs completely from the digest generated in C++ with the openssl-library.

command-line:

```
openssl dgst -binary -sha256 MyFile.txt
```

c++:

```
BIO* bio = BIO_new_file("MyFile.txt", "rb");
if (bio != NULL)
{
   OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
   const EVP_MD* md = EVP_sha256();

   if (md != NULL)
   {
      EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

      if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, md, NULL))
      {
         const int bufLength = 4096;
         unsigned char buf[bufLength];
         unsigned int len;

         while (BIO_read(bio, buf, bufLength))
            EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, buf, bufLength);

         unsigned char digest[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];

         int ok = EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx, digest, &len); // ok == 1; digest in variable "digest" is totally different from the one calculated on command-line
      }
      
      EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx);

      BIO_free_all(bio);
     }
}
```

why is the digest calculated via c++ totally different, than the one calculated on command-line? (MyFile.txt has no line-breaks or whitespaces in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You handle the reading wrong. With this codechange, the hash is correct:

```
            int readlen;

            while ( (readlen = BIO_read(bio, buf, bufLength)) > 0)
            {
                EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, buf, readlen);
            }
```

In general, you should have more error handling to make your code more robust.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this didn't work =>readlen is "always" 1 (except when the file is read to the end)

Comment: i've also tried reading the file with QT (QFile.readAll), there the hash also differs from the one calculated on command-line

Comment: Yes it works. Did you copy the while clause verbatim? Parentheses are important. When I read my test file, it read 4096 bytes 2 times, followed by 1655 bytes in the last read. And the hex hash matches the command line ssl hash exactly.

Comment: thanks, when converting the binary hash to hex they are identical